# C# storing updated values in datatable so that it can also be stored in datagridview

Tags: c#

How to update datatable values through datagridview which will be stored in excel sheet... so that the changes will updated in datagridview when loading excel file next time

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about **"Taking data from GridView and storing that data in DataTable in asp.net"**, then try this

```
DataTable yourDT = new DataTable();
yourDT.Columns.Add("content");
// Add your columns here
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvParent.Rows)
{
            string Content = row.Cells[0].Text; // If you are using databound columns
            string ContentFromLabel = ((Label)row.Cells[0].FindControl("YourLabel")).Text;// If you are using Template column
// get more columns like this that you have added
            yourDT.Rows.Add(new object[] { Content, .... other data });
}
```